# How to merge 2 tables in order to get the wish date and last order date for each subcategory?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a **wish** table like below for example, this table has the data about the wishlist details of customers

```
EmailAddress    wish_created_date   Category
a@gmail.com     Aug-3-2021          Curtain
a@gmail.com     Aug-2-2021          Table
b@gmail.com     Aug-2-2021          Sofa
b@gmail.com     Aug-2-2021          Sofa
b@gmail.com     Aug-2-2021          Sofa
e@gmail.com     Aug-3-2021          Sofa
e@gmail.com     Aug-3-2021          Sofa
e@gmail.com     Aug-3-2021          Sofa
```

Then I have another table called - **last_category_orders**. This table has the data about customer last order date in each category. There are 4 categories
Curtain,
Table,
Chair,
Sofa

```
EmailAddress    last_curtain_order  last_table_order    last_sofa_order last_chair_order
a@gmail.com     Aug-5-2021           Aug-3-2021     
b@gmail.com                                              Aug-5-2021 
c@gmail.com     Aug-9-2021                                               Aug-9-2021
d@gmail.com                          Aug-9-2021          Aug-9-2021 
e@gmail.com                                                              Aug-10-2021
```

**Expected results**
My final table should look like below,

```
EmailAddress    wish_created_date   Category            last_cat_order
a@gmail.com     Aug-3-2021          Curtain             Aug-5-2021
a@gmail.com     Aug-2-2021          Table               Aug-3-2021
b@gmail.com     Aug-2-2021          Sofa                Aug-5-2021
b@gmail.com     Aug-2-2021          Sofa                Aug-5-2021
b@gmail.com     Aug-2-2021          Sofa                Aug-5-2021
e@gmail.com     Aug-3-2021          Sofa                null
e@gmail.com     Aug-3-2021          Sofa                null
e@gmail.com     Aug-3-2021          Sofa                null
```

The final table should be left join of **wish** with **last_category_orders** table, with last_cat_order date.

Example: a@gmail.com created a wish for curtain. The last_curtain_order for a@gmail.com was Aug-5-2021. This has to be displayed in the final table.

I am stuck on how to get the results in the final table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql does not have unpivot operator so you can use union below to achieve it

```
select w.*, cat.date last_cat_order
from wish w
left join 
(
select 
max(last_curtain_order ) date, 'curtain' category, emailaddress
from  last_category_orders LC
group by emailaddress
union 
max(last_table_order) date,'table' category, emailaddress
from  last_category_orders LC
group by emailaddress
union 
max(last_sofa_order) date,'sofa' category, emailaddress
from  last_category_orders LC
group by emailaddress
union 
max(last_chair_order) date,'chair' category, emailaddress
from  last_category_orders LC
group by emailaddress
)Cat
on cat.emailaddress = w.emailaddress
and cat.category =w.Category
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join by the id of the product category. Use case, then u join must be correctly
Example

```
select
    t1.emailAddress,
    t1.wish_creater_date,
    t1.category_id,(exm curtain = 1, table = 2 ...)
    case
        when t1.category_id = 1 then t2.last_curtain_order
        when t1.category_id = 2 then t2.last_table_order
        when t1.category_id = 3 then t2.last_sofa_order
        when t1.category_id = 4 then t2.last_chair_order
    end as last_cat_order
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on
    t2.emailAddress = t1.emailAddress
```

Comment: @SoniaS . . . This seems like the better solution.